# Need help to make correct select query in DB2

Tags: sql, select, db2, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

I haven't done yet relevant course at university so I can't be sure that this query correct, it works but it looks too weird so I need review and some feedback.

I've the following `IP_TABLE` table with mixed Primary Key: `ID` + `IP`

```
----------------------------------
|  ID  | DATE      | IP          |
----------------------------------
|  1   | 2016-10-01| 1.2.3.10    |
----------------------------------
|  2   | 2016-10-20| 1.2.3.20    |
----------------------------------
|  2   | 2016-10-25| 1.2.3.40    |
----------------------------------
|  3   | 2016-10-01| 1.2.3.10    |
----------------------------------
|  3   | 2016-10-25| 1.2.3.25    |
----------------------------------
```

I want to get all rows where data has maximum value among same ids, like following:

```
----------------------------------
|  ID  | DATE      | IP          |
----------------------------------
|  1   | 2016-10-01| 1.2.3.10    |
----------------------------------
|  2   | 2016-10-25| 1.2.3.40    |
----------------------------------
|  3   | 2016-10-25| 1.2.3.25    |
----------------------------------
```

Right now I have two queries which do the job:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ID, MAX(DATE) AS LAST_DATE
                    FROM IP_TABLE 
                GROUP BY ID
                    ORDER BY MAX(DATE) ASC) AS T1
            LEFT JOIN IP_TABLE AS T2
                ON T1.ID = T2.ID
                    AND T1.LAST_DATE = T2.DATE
```

It looks weird that I join table to itself, doesn't know is it correct.

Second working query is following:

```
SELECT * FROM IP_TABLE AS T1
    WHERE DATE = (SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM IP_TABLE WHERE ID = T1.ID)
```

It afraid that this query can lead to performance impact, because it looks like O(n^2), i.e. for each row it looks across all rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function like `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT ID, DATE, IP
FROM (
   SELECT ID, DATE, IP,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID 
                             ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS rn      
   FROM IP_TABLE) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

`ROW_NUMBER` enumerates records within each `ID` slice, starting with the record having the latest `DATE` value (due to the `ORDER BY DATE DESC` clause). Hence, the outer query picks the latest-per-`ID` record.

Comment: Thank you It works, but can you please provide some explanation how does it works?